# Decorator pattern and structuremap with multiple decorators

Tags: dependency-injection, structuremap

I am trying to wire up a series of decorators using structure map but am having some issues.

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443464/structuremap-and-the-decorator-pattern) which got me to the point where i can have a single decorated class, but i can't seem to get multiple levels of decorator working.  What i have is class A which takes a connection string as a parameter, and then class B and class C which are both decorators for class A.  I can get structuremap to create B which wraps A but I cant seem to get C wrapping B wrapping A.

This works for 1 level:

```
For<IQuestionRepository> ()
                .Use<LinqToSqlQuestionRepository> ()
                    .Ctor<string>("connectionString")
                    .Is(x=>System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["aspnetdbConnectionString"].ConnectionString)
                .EnrichWith (x=>new RecentQuestionCachedRepository(x))
```

and I thought that just adding another EnrichWith would work like so:

```
For<IQuestionRepository> ()
                .Use<LinqToSqlQuestionRepository> ()
                    .Ctor<string>("connectionString")
                    .Is(x=>System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["aspnetdbConnectionString"].ConnectionString)
                .EnrichWith (x=>new RecentQuestionCachedRepository(x))
                .EnrichWith (y=>new FeaturedQuestionCachedRepository(y));
```

but this just gives me a FeaturedQuestionCachedRepository which wraps a LinqToSqlQuestionRepository but the RecentQuestionCachedRepository is not anywhere in the  stack.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do it in a single EnrichWith call:

```
.EnrichWith (x=> 
  new FeaturedQuestionCachedRepository(
  new RecentQuestionCachedRepository(x)
  )
)
```